# How to add busy cursor to reactstrap modal button in onClick function. The function is a promise

Tags: reactjs, sass, reactstrap

I used the reactstrap modal from https://reactstrap.github.io/components/modals/

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, Modal, ModalHeader, ModalBody, ModalFooter } from 'reactstrap';

class ModalExample extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      modal: false
    };

    this.toggle = this.toggle.bind(this);
  }

  toggle() {
    this.setState({
      modal: !this.state.modal
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Button color="danger" onClick={this.toggle}>{this.props.buttonLabel}</Button>
        <Modal isOpen={this.state.modal} fade={false} toggle={this.toggle} className={this.props.className}>
          <ModalHeader toggle={this.toggle}>Modal title</ModalHeader>
          <ModalBody>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </ModalBody>
          <ModalFooter>
            <Button color="primary" onClick={this.toggle}>Do Something</Button>{' '}
            <Button color="secondary" onClick={this.toggle}>Cancel</Button>
          </ModalFooter>
        </Modal>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default ModalExample;
```

the onclick function of my 'do something' button is a promise. And this function is defined in another component. I want to add busy cursor when the promise function is loading data. How to realize this? I have a scss file for my project.

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, you'll need to add a CSS class to an element, execute your promise, and when it completes or fails, you remove the class. The class can look something like this.

```
.wait-cursor {
  cursor: wait;
}
```

Comment: thx. But what method can I select the button component and remove this cursor when I am in the function of another component class?

Comment: It's going to be based on how you've coded your project. You can just have it as an event listener on the document, or respond to a state change in redux, or other possibilities